Is there an opportunity to render an array with map method backwards in DOM structure in ReactJS?
For example, I have several items in an array. I render them with map so they appear layer after layer. In DOM structure it looks like you push elements into the array of a parent node. I want it to render backwards like you use unshift for the parent-node-array (layer-under-layer).
I haven't found anything specific to solve this, maybe you could help
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
...
return(
     <div className="stack-container">
            {cardsData?.map(({ image, id }, index) => (
                <Card
                    drag={index === cardsData.length - 1}
                    key={id}
                    id={id}
                    index={index}
                    onVote={(result: boolean) => handleVote(id, result, index)}
                    forcedId={forcedId}
                >
                    <motion.div className="meme-card-wrapper" data-id={id} key={`meme-card-${id}`}>
                        <MemeCard image={image} />
                    </motion.div>
                </Card>
            ))}
        </div>
)

Here you can see the result if I'm using z-index with negative values
It's kinda the result I'm expecting because the first element that appears in the tree also appears first on the screen. Still my grab gesture is blocked with this solution, so I'm looking for another one or a way to fix this one.

Does Array.prototype.toReversed() help. It returns a new array containing the items from the source array but in the reverse order?

Not really, it just reverses the array. I need to reverse the order in tree rendering. It's kinda difficult to describe but I hope you get the point. Currently rendering works as if I put one layer on top of another. I want to put one layer under another, so the last child element that was formed from the last element of the array was on the top level in parent node tree. For instance:
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3]
return arr.map(item => item);
Outcome:

3
2
1
0

Please update your question with details of what you've got and what you're trying to do. Perhaps you should also include a [mcve].

I tried dinamically numering z-index an it worked but it blocks the grab gesture for <motion.div></motion.div> from FramerMotion that I'm using in the project.

Updated the question
